# Set Values (Selection) in a multiple Select

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I use Chosen jQuery plugin on a multiple select element.

```
<select class="chosen-select" data-order="true" name="multiselect[]" id="multiselect" multiple="true">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>
```

I want to retrieve and to display the options value in the order they were selected (clicked).
for exmple iam selected one  two three
 i want show result: slected one , two , three

Comment: You've to maintain the array of the selected items. For that **1.** Create an empty array **2.** Bind change event on the element **3.** Add the selected item in the array if not already else remove it from array.

Comment: @Tushar #2 actually needs to be done in event callback of the plugin

Comment: If you've tried some code to solve the problem, add it in the question.